# SQL Server Stored Procedure Error in Database Project [Visual Studio]

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in a Database Project. I am having errors for all the parameters in the stored procedure and I get an error

> The model has an element that has the same name dbo.xyz

If I replace my `CREATE PROCEDURE` command with `ALTER PROCEDURE`, the errors are gone but according to my understanding that we shall always write `CREATE PROCEDURE` in the project and based on the target DB while publishing it will handle automatically whether to CREATE or ALTER.

Can someone help me please. I have also looked up some solutions which says that the `Model.xml` file contains old code which needs to be replaced. But my DB-Project folder don't have any file like that.

Any help is really appreciated. I am new in handling this database project.

Comment: If the database object exists then you can't CREATE is again. You have to drop the procedure to CREATE it again. Otherwise you can modify(alter) it using ALTER PROCEDURE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `CREATE PROCEDURE` in a Database Project. If the error goes away when you change it to `ALTER PROCEDURE` then it sounds like it is already defined somewhere else in your project.

Check to see if ANY other object in your project is using that name already, including tables and views.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes I had another stored procedure with the same name inside a folder in the DB project. I get it now why I had all the errors. Thank you. I am extremely new to this DB Project thing.

Comment: @SouradipRoy, it's good that you found a useful answer. Please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the grey check mark to the left. It rewards the person who answered with some reputation points, and you get some, too. You can also choose to up-vote the answer by clicking on the up arrow next to the answer.

Comment: @EricBrandt Yes I already upvoted it but forgot to accept. Which I did now, Thanks for pointing it out.